# Can you restrict access to python scripts to two google sheets when authorising python scripts via OAuth Client ID ServiceAccount credentials

Tags: python, google-sheets

Can you restrict access to certain google sheet workbooks, with multiple tab sheets within each (eg Company & Overview), when authorising python scripts via OAuth Client ID ServiceAccount credentials, where I believe that the  google-sheets-secret-.json file, has to be copied to the same folder as your python scripts.

The following code details how the each of the six python scripts point to my ServiceAccountCredentials via the google-Sheets-secret.json file:

```
    # access to Company and Overview google sheets:

    scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
    creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('google-sheets-secret.json', scope)
    # The abovefile I believe has to copied and placed in the same folder as your scripts.
    client = gspread.authorize(creds)
    
    # open spreadsheet
    spreadsheet_key = configs.overview_key
    sheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheet_key)
```

There are six python scripts, that need to either input/output data from the Google Company and for Overview workbooks, data is pulled from both these workbooks based on Tickers or other criteria, to get data from the API. and inputs results from the API back to these two Google workbooks.

Both of the two python Company and Overview scripts refer to a third python script that to extract the API and Sheet IDS for the two Google workbooks as follows:

1. enter code here "api_key"
2. enter code here `overview_key' (ie your google sheet id for the Overview sheet)
3. enter code here `company_key' (ie sheet id for the Company sheet).

Is it possible to restrict access for the python scripts within a folder, to be only able to read/write the two various sheet tabs within the two google workbooks (ie not allow access other google applications (Gmail etc), if yes, how can I do that. If not able to do this, is it possible to create a warning message to alert me that illegal activity is about to occur, then restrict transactions.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You will be able to access the spreadsheets that have been shared with the service account or have been created by it. No more, no less. Consider providing more information about your situation.

Comment: ! would like to know two things:

Comment: I would like to know two things: (1) How do I setup the OAuth Client ID ServiceAccount credentials to only allow the the python scripts, to be only able to read and write to the  Company and Overview spreadsheets only, no access to other google spreadsheets, or other google apps eg gmail. (2) If not able to do re item 1, can you set up a warning message to advise of an attempt of illegal activity, and have the ability to delete the transaction.

Comment: You cannot set up credentials so that they can only be used by a certain script nor to restrict access to specific spreadsheets (although you can restrict other API's by not enabling them in your project). Apart from that, anyone that was your credentials can write a program to access whatever spreadsheets are available to the service account, there's nothing you can do about it. Are there other people (who you don't trust) who have access to the service account credentials and that you don't trust? How did that came to be the case?

Comment: No it is not that I don't trust, but to for me if I cannot manage/restrict access to other google sheets and google applications I will not allow access for this project. You can now close this question.

Comment: `You can now close this question` does that mean you got your question answered? What was it? Would you consider posting an answer explaining this?

Comment: Yes I I got my question answered, please close this question.

Comment: I already voted to close this question, but two more votes are needed. You, as the user who posted the question, do have the ability of deleting the question (or closing it if you have enough rep, I think https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300117). But, you should only do that if you think an answer to this question cannot be useful to other users. Otherwise, consider posting an answer to this or, if you think the answer came through my previous comments, I'll post it.